# Display HTML Pages from Documents Directory in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.2

I am unzipping an EPUB file and storing it in the Documents directory within a folder.

Now I would like display all the HTML pages in a UIWebView and display all the HTML page names in a tableView.

For example, if i have `Introduction_1.html` then I would like to display "Introduction_1" in the tableview and so on.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here the documentDirectory stands for the path of document directory. If your files are situated at place other than document directory , obviously you may place the path there.

```
  NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentDirectory];
    NSString *strFinalPath = [dirContents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OEBPS"];
    for (NSString *tString in strFinalPath) 
    {
        if ([tString hasSuffix:@".html"])
        {    
            NSLog(@"File name -> %@",tString);    
        }
    }
```

Hope ,it was helpful.

Comment: Thank u for the reply , i will be trying with this.

Comment: my path is in filepath variable and in that path i have a folder named with this"OEBPS", can u kindly say me how can i give the path now.

Comment: still if you are not getting , please put the NSLog(@"filepath -> %@",filepath); and print the path here, so that I can understand about which path are you talking

Comment: thank u so much for the reply, i could not see ur reply, i will check now.